# Make an old TV screen material

Tags: materials

How could I make an old TV material? I've tried some nodes, but I don't get the dessired result

[image]

Comment: Could you show what you've done?

Comment: I think he's just talking about the milky gray screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Final]

### Base material:

In *Node Editor* add *Subsurface Scattering* shader set *Radius* to *1.5* to have nice darkened corners, select desired color (for example *#CCE7D7*) then add *Glossy* shader and set *Roughness* to *0*. Add *Mix* shader, connect them and as a factor add *Input > Fresnel* to fake PBR reflections.

[image: Material]

Now you will have something like this:

[image: Final_1]

### White spot:

To add this white spot in the center of the screen we will need *Gradient Texture* as color for *Subsurface Scattering*. We will also need some simple *UV unwrap* for the screen, mine is simple *Project from view (bounds)* from *Front Ortho* view.

Add *Input > Texture Coordinates* then *Vector > Mapping*, now in *Mapping* node choose *Texture* tab and set *Scale* to *0.7* (X, Y, Z) and *Location* to *0.5* (X, Y). **Those values may vary based on your mesh/unwrap!**

Now add *Texture > Gradient*, set it to *Spherical*, add *Converter > Color Ramp*, change black color to the one from base material steps and move white color to the left (more to the left, bigger white spot).

Connect it to the *Subsurface Scaterring* color slot and we are done here.

[image: Material_2]

**Note** that I'm using Environment Texture for lightning and reflections. You will have it packed in .blend file.

**Blend file:**

[image]

**Edit:**

I tought that I can crank it up a little bit by adding this white spot in the center of the screen. More details above, I think that extending previous steps would be much better then creating it belowe edit.

Comment: If you will have any problems with UV mapping this white spot, add your blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ in your question and I will look at it. Don't forget to comment here to give me notification ;)