# How to make my water look Murky?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation

Blender noob here again! I'm working on making a Swamp scene and I'm curious how I can make my water look murky/smokey. Would I need a smoke simulator in the system too? Or is it a materials thing? Any suggestions?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78504/realistic-aquarium-water

Comment: It depends if its for an animation..If it is static, then i suggest using a dirty, green texture and making it the same roughness as the water, and placing it on top of the water, or in certain areas.

Comment: You'll be using a textured volumetric material for the material...the texture for this could be based on a smoke simulation or just a noise texture...

Comment: https://youtu.be/Z_mqcwhaOwI

Answer (score 8):

[image: final]

This method will be pretty hard for your hardware, but it's the only reasonable way (I can think of) to make it look good from any angle.

Any other method I've tried like using gradient to change Roughness, Transmission, mixing with other shader is looking similar from the side but they will not work looking from above.

It's really simple setup.

[image: nodes]

First of all you will need to use **Separate XYZ** to be able to create gradual transition between dirt and clear water.

Next you can use this separation to create water color change (not necessary) and use **Principled** or **Glass** shader for water itself.

Lastly add **Volume Scatter** and **Absorption** to make "dirt" inside your water. **Multiply** node will help with **Density** - higher value = denser dirt.

Don't forget to crank up **Light Paths > Volume** to something higher than 0. I've used 2 in this example.

[image]

Comment: Also look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63505/make-an-old-tv-screen-material/63519#63519 and here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87553/need-help-making-a-frosted-light-bulb-material/87635#87635 Those answers could help you a bit.