# coconut milk material in Eevee - how do i do it?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I need to make a semitransparent and glossy liquid coconut material like the left picture. With the ability to tweak its whiteness and transparency, so that it looks like right picture.
If you think you have an answer, please post your material setup.

[image: examples]

Comment: This effect could be achievable with use of Volume shader, sadly EEVEE can't render Volume in the shape of the mesh it's inside. Check here Cycles version of something similar: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107236/how-to-make-my-water-look-murky/107251#107251