# What's the physically correct way to mix an emission shader with a non-emissive cover material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light, eevee-render-engine, pbr

How do I make a PBR emissive dielectric material such as: a computer screen, a glow stick, or the white tube of a CFL light?

Do I *MIX* or *ADD* the Emission with the Principled BSDF?
Should I mix it with Fresnel?

Comment: Well technically speaking, if you are looking for photo realism and want a physically accurate representation, those should be two separate surfaces all together with different geometry. One for the glass, one for the actual emissive surface

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63505/make-an-old-tv-screen-material